# Get type fully listed out (for copy/pasting)

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am needing to write a migration between two app versions. The `store` in version 1 has certain type. And in version 2 has another state. In my migration script I want to include both types. When I hover over the type in vscode, it gives me a high level view, in that it doesn't deeply open things, screenshot below:

We see it gives `app: AppShape`. But I want it to give me the details in side app shape like:

```
app: {
   banner: string;
}
```

So I can copy this to my migration script as so:

```
type StateVersion1 = any; // i would paste type here
type StateVersion2 = any; // i would paste type here

function migrateToVersion2(state: StoreVersion1): StoreVersion2
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

[image]

Comment: I sometimes use this utility type to deeply expand types, it doesn't always work but you can try it. Code:
`type ExpandDeep<T> = T extends object
  ? T extends Function 
      ? T
      : T extends infer O
        ? { [K in keyof O]: ExpandDeep<O[K]> }
        : never
  : T;

type Tmp = ExpandDeep<StoreState>;`
Then hover over `Tmp`.

Comment: Darn so close! It starts to show "6 more..." and stuff haha. Thanks very much for this try. Here is screenshot - https://i.imgur.com/2crmS5l.png

Comment: Try to expand and copy/paste it step by step. For `enrollments` you can do: `type Tmp = ExpandDeep<StoreState[...]...['enrollments'];` if this makes sense.

Comment: Oh true! This is at least a workaround till an easier one-highlight one-copy solution. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, there must be a way to get the full type but probably by using vscode typescript api. I'm curious if you will make it work in the end by doing it step-by-step.